# Reset dropdown value based on a different dropdown value ....?! (help)

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, dropdown

**I am using SharePoint 2016 on-prem.**

I have been searching for a solution and I am not a programer :/
Is there a method to reset a dropdown value to its default "Select" when a different dropdown has been set to "External"???

I have 2 dropdowns:

DropDown1 = Internal | External 
DropDown2 = Select ... | various numbers

If you select Internal than the DropDown 2 becomes available and you can select some numbers. Now, if you change DropDown1 to External then the DropDown1 fades out BUT the information is still selected.

Ideally, would be cool to be able to clear the value out once DropDown 1 = External.

Is it something you can help me with?? 
I know I am supposed to get some code myself but ... :( sorry not sure about it.

Comment: Is this question concerning SharePoint Online (Office 365) or SharePoint On-prem (SharePoint 2013 / 2016)?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is SharePoint2016 on prem.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to do this with client-side code, if you're not yourself a developer, and do not have one on your team, it's not adviseable to take that path.

In SharePoint Online you have PowerApps which will solve your issue without a problem, and most importantly, without any code. However in SharePoint On-premises you are far more limited.

My strongest advice is to keep it as it is, using standard functionality, you can use field descriptions to instruct the user on what to do. For instance, a description on Dropdown2 could read: "For Internal, please select a number".

Alternatively you can use a third-party tool such as Nintex Forms or SharePoint Forms Designer by Plumsail, of course these come at some cost, but it's pennies compared to having a developer maintaining a form every time it breaks because of a SharePoint update.

Comment: Hey Helge, yes sure ... coding is not easy :) and yes Nintex 2016 is what I am using to create the forms etc. Indeed, in a perfect world you would expect the user knowing what to select but trust me ... there are some "non-sense members of staff" who click about without using the logic lol and hence why I am here trying to make it bullet proof :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the InfoPath form.

Add rule to DropDown1. When the DropDown1 field value is changed, set the DropDown2 value.
 [image]

[image]

Here is a demo about [how to clear drop down value](https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/Infopath-form-clearinactive-ddfields.html).